# Matplotlib overlapping color and marker

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for color, marker in [('g', 'x'), ('r', 'o'), ('b', '^')]:
    ax.scatter(x[:100],y[:100],z[:100], marker=marker, color=color, s=50, alpha=.3)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

gets me this

[image]

but I want this instead

[image]

I tried changing facecolor and edgecolor but no help.

The tutorial code seems to work the way I want and doesn't overlap the markers and gets the colors correct. Is there an easier way to do this without the loop?

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    return (vmax - vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
n = 100
for c, m, zl, zh in [('g', 'o', -50, -25), ('b', '^', -30, -5), ('r', 'x', -30, -5)]:
    xs = randrange(n, 23, 32)
    ys = randrange(n, 0, 100)
    zs = randrange(n, zl, zh)
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, edgecolor=(0,0,0,0), c=c, marker=m)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Comment: What are x,y, and z in your code? You're plotting the same values three times and that's why your markers overlap.

Comment: Victor Chubukov is right about the overlapping issue. About the color, It seems that the scatter method does not work exactly the same way for 2D and 3D plots, in 3D you should use c="r" instead of color="r" (which works fine in 2D). You may also use edgecolors="face".